# Flickering or jagged movements when sprites move along a curvilinear path

Tags: 2d, sprites

I'm making a top-down zoomable 2D game. I can't achieve a perfectly smooth curvilinear movement of the sprites, not even when I have a pixel perfect reproduction. I tried different approaches and I always ended up with either flickering or jagged movements.

I'll use this sprite as an example:

[image: example sprite]

---

#### Approach 1

*Sprites moving freely in floats. Sampling the texture with a linear filter. MSAA enabled.*

When the sprites move at a velocity that's not a multiple of 1 pixel/frame I see them flickering, especially when they have certain pixel patterns (like a thin black outline around).

For example with the above sprite I get the following effect:

[image: Curvilinear motion flickering]

That's due to different sampling and approximation of the underlying texture between different frames. For example when a black texel of the sprite lies between two pixels, then the pixel color is the linear interpolation of two near texel and it changes to grey. Then in the next frame the texel again occupies a whole pixel and its color again becomes black.

[image: Different sampling example]

Moreover when the zoom-out kicks in and the sprite isn't reproduced 1:1 on the screen, the flickering is much worse and other artifacts come out (they are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785291/getting-giggly-effect-when-slowly-moving-a-sprite/35829604#35829604)).

[image: Curvilinear motion zoom-out flickering and artifacts]

The problems are less noticeable at 4K, but a lot more at lower resolutions.

Using a nearest filter to sample the texture makes the movement smoother (but jagged), but it only works when the zoom level is pixel-perfect. Otherwise there are still the problems shown on the gif above.

---

#### Approach 2

*Rounding the sprite positions to the nearest pixel. Sampling the texture with a linear filter. MSAA enabled.*

With this approach I have no flickering, because whatever is the sampling of the texture, then it remains consistent among frames:

[image: Rounding to the nearest pixel - zoom out coherence]

How the sprite is sampled:

[image: Downsized sampling example]

The upper and right outlines disappears from the screen, but they are absent in any frame, whatever the position. So there's no flickering.

However there is a side-effect. When the sprite moves slowly along a curvilinear path, I see a jagged movement (the gif also has a slower framerate (~30fps), but the movement is somehow jagged also at 60fps):

[image: Rounding to the nearest pixel - jagged]

Moreover if it moves at a velocity that's not a multiple of 1 pixel/frame, the movement is jerky, because in some frames it moves of 3 pixels, in other frames it moves of 2 pixels and so on.

The only situation in which I really see a smooth movement is when the sprite moves vertically, horizontally or diagonally, and its velocity is a multiple of 1 pixel/frame. But when it does a curvilinear movement or also a linear movement on an arbitrary direction (different from the aforementioned ones), then I see some visual imperfections.

---

None of the above approaches is fully satisfactory. Do I have to live with these problems or is there any other approach I can try to achieve a better smoothness?

Comment: Has your image been scaled at all? [Non-1:1 mapping of texture texels to screen pixels can cause shimmering artifacts similar to what you're seeing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829604/3064164).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's somewhat related to my problem. But here it's noticeable also when the sprite isn't scaled. When the black outline lies between two pixels, then it's not black anymore, but it's split in two grey pixels. Then in the next frame it appears black again. I think this is the problem behind the flickering. The white square with a one-pixel outline it's an exaggeration. But the problem also occurs with normal sprites.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use nearest neighbour / point filtering, rather than bilinear, if you don't want to blend the line between adjacent pixels like that.

Comment: With a nearest filter I have a worse output. In curvilinear motion I see a jagged movement and the outline completely disapper in some frames. I don't know, maybe a perfect curvilinear output isn't achievable at all on a screen made of pixel. I just asked to be sure I didn't miss anything.

Comment: If the line is disappearing, then you don't have a 1:1 scale. Fix that first.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I had a wrong parameter and the scale was 2:1. With a pixel-perfect representation and nearest neighbor the result is great, no flickering at all! And the jagged movement is unnoticeable. However if I zoom out I sadly have artifacts of all sorts (those you mentioned in the first comment). I know that maybe this is another question, but is there any way to avoid flickering, without being forced to have a pixel-perfect representation (i.e. with any level of zoom)?

Comment: Is this square representative of your real sprites? If so, we might be able to use signed distance field techniques to get a consistently crisp appearance over a range of scales. The downside is that this can limit the number of different colours/gradients used in a single sprite, compared to an uncompressed raster where we can paint every pixel a different colour independently.

Comment: No, that sprite it's just an example that exaggerates the problem, the real sprite is a normal one, a character moving on the map. However I'm fine with the appearance of the downsized sprite I achieve with approach #2, even if the outline disappears. The only problem is the more noticeable jagged movement, that makes the motion not smooth. Can the signed distance field techique help with this?